# how to edit single row in rich:dataTable

Tags: modal-dialog, richfaces, panel

i have to edit a row in a table using rich faces 4 and modal panel. I am new one so please tell me in details and i know to make a table in rich faces. i already searched so many things but not getting any fruitful

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: till now i made a dynamic rich table using rich table tag

Comment: can you add your source code?
or is your issue related to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881174/render-richextendeddatatable/21903947#21903947

Comment: <rich:panel> 
        <f:facet name="header"> 
       
        </f:facet>

Comment: <h:form id="form"> 
        <rich:dataTable value="#{userControls.lusers}" var="_employee" 
            iterationStatusVar="it" id="employeeList" rows="15">

Comment: <rich:column> 
                <f:facet name="header">First Name</f:facet> 
                <h:outputText value="#{_employee.firstName}" /> 
            </rich:column>

Comment: <rich:column> 
                <a4j:commandLink value="#{_employee.firstName}" render="popDiv" execute="@this" >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{_employee.firstName}" value="arjun"/>
    <rich:componentControl target="personModalPanel" operation="show" event="click" />
</a4j:commandLink>

Comment: </rich:column> 
             
        </rich:dataTable> 
 
   <rich:popupPanel id="personModalPanel" modal="true" width="400" height="400">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:outputText value="Edit Person" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>

Comment: <f:facet name="controls">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:graphicImage value="/images/icon/edit.png" styleClass="hidelink" id="hidelink" >
                    <rich:componentControl target="personModalPanel" operation="hide" event="onclick" />
                </h:graphicImage>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>
</rich:popupPanel>
    </h:form> 
    </rich:panel>

Comment: please help me  on this topic generally i have to edit row in a table using riches faces 4 and row panel

Comment: How about, try first to edit your table without a popupPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149141/richfaces-show-details-in-popup-commandbutton-action-and-popuppanel/21149308#21149308) for question *"Richfaces: show details in popup [commandbutton, action and popupPanel]"*. It works in RichFaces 4.x with rowClick.

Or here is example with `commandLink`:

```
    <a4j:commandLink action="#{actionBean.setupTransactionDetails}"
        event="onclick" render="transactionDetails"
        oncomplete="#{rich:component('transactionDetails')}.show()"
        styleClass="rich-link">
        <h:outputText value="#{res.transactionType}" />
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{res.transactionId}"
                target="#{profile.transactionId}" />
    </a4j:commandLink>
```

But I prefer updated version like this:

```
    <a4j:jsFunction name="showDetail" action="#{actionBean.setupTransactionDetails}"
    oncomplete="#{rich:component('transactionDetails')}.show();"
    render="transactionDetails">
        <a4j:param name="id" assignTo="#{profile.transactionId}"
            converter="javax.faces.Long" />
    </a4j:jsFunction>

    <rich:dataTable id="txnTable" rows="#{referenceData.recordsPerPage}"
    style="width: 100%" rowClasses="oddrow, evenrow"
    value="#{profile.transactions}" var="res" sortMode="single">
        <h:column width="110">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.transactionType}" />
            </f:facet>
            <a4j:commandLink onclick="showDetail('#{res.transactionId}');"
                value="#{res.transactionType}" />
        </h:column>
    </rich:dataTable>

    <rich:popupPanel id="transactionDetails" autosized="true"
        style="max-height:600px;">
        <!-- f:facet name="header" and f:facet name="controls" here -->
        <h:form id="transactionDetailsForm">
            <!-- some details here -->
        </h:form>
    </rich:popupPanel>
```

Profile backing bean

```
private Long transactionId; // + getter and setter
```

Action backing bean

```
    public void setupTransactionDetails() {
        Transaction txn = DAO.getInstance().get(Transaction.class, getProfile().getTransactionId());
        transactionForm.setup(txn);
    }
```

In case if you use EL 2.2 (or higher) you can call action bean method with parameter.

Comment: i appreciate your effort, Ok please send me simplified version with command Link also i want to try this also

Comment: can you please send me simplified version with command Link for edit row of a table using rich faces 4